# babel 7 and function bind operator

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I plan to migrate to babel 7 and I want to stop using presets in favor of manual adding plug-ins. I like the binding operator and I see that there are several packages: @babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind, @babel/plugin-syntax-function-bind and babel-plugin-transform-function-bind.
Which one should I use and why?

Answer (score 0):

you should use @babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind, it does the both recognition and the transform.

@babel/plugin-syntax-function-bind only allow the :: operator but do not transform it.

and it seems  babel 7 move all plugin under @babal scope